# How to get id from a button if I know the name - javascript

Tags: javascript, this

I have some buttons, with same name `anOldFile` and I want to get theirs id, or `innerHTML` if I clicked. I think this is a good start, but I don't know how to continue, if this is good:

```
    document.getElementsByName('anOldFile').addEventListener('click', changeOffCanvasContent(this));

    function changeOffCanvasContent(e) {
         //???
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [`getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) returns a nodelist, you need to iterate and bind event handler to each element and just pass the function reference.

```
document.getElementsByName('anOldFile').forEach(function (elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('click', changeOffCanvasContent);
});
```

It will set the context of `this` to element which invoked the event

```
function changeOffCanvasContent(e) {
    console.log(this.id);
    console.log(e.target.id);
}
```

Comment: I got this error: "document.getElementsByName(...).addEventListener is not a function"

Answer (score 1):

you have several problems there. Fist of all `getElementsByName` returns array of node elements, so you have to `addEventListener` to each one of them. Secondly you are registering eventListener function incorrectly. You should not call a handler function in addEventListener, but just pass a handler name. 
Thridly in the function definition you can get hold of element by referencing target element as follows:

Whole code snippet that does the job should look as follows:

`var elements = document.getElementsByName('anOldFile');`

`function changeOffCanvasContent(e) {
   console.log(e.target.innerHTML);
   console.log(e.target.id);
}`

`for(var i = 0; i< elements.length-1; i++){
     elements[i].addEventListener('click', changeOffCanvasContent);
}`